# Django testing: reuse `setUp` for multiple classes/files?

Tags: python, django

I have a growing set of classes used for testing. However, almost all of them use the same test scenario. To avoid duplication, I have created a superclass

```
class CommonScenario(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        create_products
        create_customers
        ...

class Test1(CommonScenario):

class Test2(CommonScenario):
```

Although this avoids code duplication, the superclass `setUp` method is called multiple times, creating and destroying the exact same rows. Is there any way to avoid that?

Comment: No because that is the whole point, and it doesn't have anything to do with how many classes you have. `setUp` is run for *each individual test method*.

Comment: You might prefer `setUpClass` here.  Or move to pytest, which gives you much better control over session/module/class/function scoped fixtures.

Comment: Note that you have `setUpClass` too (https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.setUpClass) - but as Daniel mentions, there are reasons for executing `setUp` for each test.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers: Thanks for the reply. I realise that there's a reason for that. However, in my case, I have a large number of *read-only* queries, so it would be appropriate

Comment: @wim: thanks, that's one step in the desired